# Getting values from related models while performing loopback find()

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs, belongs-to

I am using Loopback and AngularJS to create a very simple employee database app. The application has a single Employee model defined with a **belongsTo** relationship back to the same Employee model to accommodate an employee having a manager. With this relationship in place, the intent is for the application to display the manager's name with each employee.

***The problem: I'm not able to get the manager information from within the application as I am when testing the API using Loopback Explorer.***

[Using Explorer, the employee's manager information is returned if I set the filter to include the relation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2qsL.png)

[From within the application, using the same filter, that same employee's manager information is **not** included as I would expect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVQCo.png)

Given these results, it would seem the model's relationship is setup correctly. I used **lb-ng** to generate the **lb-services.js** for use by the application's controller. The code within the controller looks like this:

```
function getEmployees() {
  Employee
    .find({"include": "manager"})
    .$promise
    .then(function(results) {
      $scope.employees = results;
    });
}
```

It is my understanding that the model find() method is issuing a GET, so I don't understand why the results are different.

I'm fairly new to Loopback and Angular, so I have to believe I'm missing something very obvious here. But I've been spinning my wheels on this for a while so thought I'd ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the results I was expecting by using the following:

```js
function getEmployees() {
      Employee
        .find({filter: {include: 'manager'}})
        .$promise
        .then(function(results) {
          $scope.employees = results;
        });
    }
```

I was clued in based on the following: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Create-AngularJS-client.html

Which differs slightly from the following: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Include-filter.html